# How do I select the value of a random cell in a range?

Tags: random, openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice Calc, I'm trying to select the numerical value of a random cell at a time, from the range H3:AF21.

I have tried the INDEX function and it does't seem to work, I get errors no matter what I choose, except if it's a single cell. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try whether the following formula fulfills your requirements.

```
=INDEX(H3:AF21,INT(RAND()*19)+1,INT(RAND()*25)+1)
```

Greetings

Axel